# Coroutines delegate exceptions

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Currently, I have some scenario like [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/generic-function-to-wrap-callbacks-with-coroutines/8885) where I have java interface callback which looks something like this.

**Java Callback**

```
interface Callback<T> {
    void onComplete(T result)

    void onException(HttpResponse response, Exception ex)
}
```

Suspending function for the above look like this

```kotlin
suspend inline fun <T> awaitCallback(crossinline block: (Callback<T>) -> Unit) : T =
     suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        block(object : Callback<T> {
            override fun onComplete(result: T) = cont.resume(result)
            override fun onException(e: Exception?) {
                e?.let { cont.resumeWithException(it) }
            }
        })
    }
```

My calling function looks like this

```
fun getMovies(callback: Callback<Movie>) {
    launch(UI) {
        awaitCallback<Movie> {
            // I want to delegate exceptions here.
            fetchMovies(it)
        }
    }
```

What I'm currently doing to catch exception is  this

```
fun getMovies(callback: CallbackWrapper<Movie>) {
    launch(UI) {
        try{
            val data = awaitCallback<Movie> {
                // I want to delegate exceptions here.
                fetchMovies(it)
            }
            callback.onComplete(data)
        }catch(ex: Exception) {
            callback.onFailure(ex)
        } 
    }
}

// I have to make a wrapper kotlin callback interface for achieving the above

interface CallbackWrapper<T> {
    fun onComplete(result: T) 

    fun onFailure(ex: Exception)
}
```

**Questions**

1. The above works but is there any better way to do this?? One of the main thing is  I'm currently migrating this code from callback so I have ~20 api calls and I don't want to add `try/catch` everywhere to delegate the result along with the exception.
2. Also, I'm only able to get `exception` from my suspending function is there any way to get both `HttpResponse` as well as the exception. Or is it possible to use existing JAVA interface.
3. Is there any better way to delegate the result from `getMovies` without using callback??

Comment: Your code posted here doesn't work... `inline` is missing, `object : Callback<T>` and the interface are not matching... besides that... I probably didn't really get why you are using that construct... wouldn't something like the following suffice? `fun getMovies(callback: Callback<Movie>) = GlobalScope.launch(UI) { val job = async { fetchMovies() }; job.getCompletionExceptionOrNull()?.apply(callback::onException); job.await().forEach(callback::onComplete) }` (note I am on Kotlin 1.3)?

Comment: I can't use async. I have to use the `awaitCallback` function that I created above bcz I'm wrapping java callback in a suspend function.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to use the `awaitCallback` [...] bcz I'm wrapping java callback in a suspend function"? In the comment before I just did the same, but I used `async` as sample... please note that the block-function passed to `launch` is already a `suspend` function. So if the only reason you use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` is to call functions that are not `suspend`, you can omit that and just use the block-function of `launch` which is a `suspend` function itself. Or why do you use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` here?

Comment: by the way: you write "the above works" (not as shown I still get some compile errors using it)... what do you do in your `fetchMovies`-function?

Comment: ok... actually my code in the comment was wrong (not so much however) ;-) should have tested it beforehand... still... I am having a hard time understanding why this `awaitCallback`/`suspendCancellableCoroutine` is really needed.

Comment: `block` function that I'm using in awaitCallback is not a suspend function of launch. It's a function parameter that I'm receiving. Same like [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/generic-function-to-wrap-callbacks-with-coroutines/8885). I think the naming is confusing.

Comment: ok... I rather meant the `block`-parameter that is passed to the `launch`-function. The `block`-parameter there is actually transforming your block into a `suspend`-function-block. So everything that is passed there actually becomes a `suspend`-function then... that's also why I don't really get why there is `awaitCallback` + `suspendCancellableCoroutine` there... but maybe I just don't get it and there is a reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any better way to delegate the result from `getMovies` without using callback?

Let me start with some assumptions:

- you're using some async HTTP client library. It has some methods to send requests, for example `httpGet` and `httpPost`. They take callbacks.
- you have ~20 methods like `fetchMovies` that send HTTP requests.

I propose to create an extension `suspend fun` for each HTTP client method that sends a request. For example, this turns an async `client.httpGet()` into a suspending `client.awaitGet()`:

```
suspend fun <T> HttpClient.awaitGet(url: String) =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine<T> { cont ->
        httpGet(url, object : HttpCallback<T> {
            override fun onComplete(result: T) = cont.resume(result)

            override fun onException(response: HttpResponse?, e: Exception?) {
                e?.also {
                    cont.resumeWithException(it)
                } ?: run {
                    cont.resumeWithException(HttpException(
                            "${response!!.statusCode()}: ${response.message()}"
                    ))
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Based on this you can write `suspend fun fetchMovies()` or any other:

```
suspend fun fetchMovies(): List<Movie> = 
        client.awaitGet("http://example.org/movies")
```

My reduced example is missing the parsing logic that turns the HTTP response into `Movie` objects, but I don't think this affects the approach.

> I'm currently migrating this code from callback so I have ~20 api calls and I don't want to add `try/catch` everywhere to delegate the result along with the exception.

You don't need a `try-catch` around each individual call. Organize your code so you just let the exception propagate upwards to the caller and have a central place where you handle exceptions. If you can't do that, it means you've got a specific way to handle each exception; then the `try-catch` is the best and idiomatic option. It's what you would write if you had a plain blocking API. Especially note how trivial it is to wrap many HTTP calls in a single `try-catch`, something you can't replicate with callbacks.

> I'm only able to get exception from my suspending function is there any way to get both `HttpResponse` as well as the exception.

This is probably not what you need. What exactly do you plan to do with the response, knowing that it's an error response? In the example above I wrote some standard logic that creates an exception from the response. If you have to, you can catch that exception and provide custom logic at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure whether you really need that `awaitCallback` or not.
If you really have lots of `Callback` already in place and that's why you used it then your functions will probably already have everything in place that works correctly with the `Callback`, e.g. I expect some methods as follows:

```
fun fetchMovies(callback : Callback<List<Movie>>) {
  try {
    // get some values from db or from a service...
    callback.onComplete(listOf(Movie(1), Movie(2)))
  } catch (e : Exception) {
    callback.onFailure(e)
  }
}
```

If you do not have something like this in place, you may not even need `awaitCallback` at all. So if your `fetchMovies` function rather has a signature as follows:

```
fun fetchMovies() : List<Movie>
```

and in `getMovies` you pass your `Callback`, then all you need is probably a simple `async`, e.g.:

```
fun getMovies(callback: Callback<List<Movie>>) {
  GlobalScope.launch { // NOTE: this is now a suspend-block, check the parameters for launch
    val job = async { fetchMovies() }
    try {
      callback.onComplete(job.await())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      callback.onException(e)
    }
  }
}
```

This sample can of course be changed to many similar variants, e.g. the following will also work:

```
fun getMovies(callback: Callback<List<Movie>>) {
  GlobalScope.launch { // NOTE: this is now a suspend-block, check the parameters for launch
    val job = async { fetchMovies() } // you could now also cancel/await, or whatever the job
    job.join() // we just join now as a sample
    job.getCompletionExceptionOrNull()?.also(callback::onFailure)
    ?: job.getCompleted().also(callback::onComplete)
  }
}
```

You could also add something like `job.invokeOnCompletion`. If you just wanted to pass any exception to your callback in your current code, you could just have used `callback.onException(RuntimeException())` at the place where you put your comment `I want to delegate exceptions here.`.

(note that I am using Kotlin 1.3 which is a RC now...)

Comment: You're right regarding signature of `fetchMovies` which currently takes a `callback` and it has `Void` return but it doesn't have `try/catch` instead it's just implementing `HttpResponse` from `okhttp` which eventually delgates the result of `onSuccess/onFailure`. I tried your last approach of using `async` the `ide` complains that stuff inside `job.getCompletionExceptionOrNull()?.also` is unused(same for failure case). Basically I'm trying to avoid using `try/catch` for handling exceptions since I have many api calls.

Comment: unused? probably not... are you sure you copied it 1:1? if your `fetchMovies` takes a `Callback`, but didn't handle the exceptions, you our out of luck and need to wrap it in a `try`/`catch`. Do you have control over the `fetchMovies`-method? Do all your methods look like that i.e. accepting a callback but didn't handle exceptions there? You may then rather exchange your `awaitCallback` with a function similar to my first shown `getMovies`-method... but instead of calling it `getMovies` you rename it to `awaitCallback` and you pass it the actual function you then use in the `async`.